# Android 4.4.4 WebView in onPageFinished() getTitle() returns page URL?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I don't know if I am misunderstanding jQueryMobile or am I seeing a Chromium Webview bug. I have an Android app that uses a webview to display jQueryMobile content. When the user navigates within the DIVs of the page, in onPageFinished() I call getTitle() to retrieve the Html page title. Sometimes, getTitle() returns the URL of the page and not the page title.

I don't understand why.

Here is a simplified version of the Android activity that demonstrates the same problem:

```
public class WebViewTitleTestActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    private TextView mTitleTextView;
    private final String TAG = "WebViewTitleTest";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                String titleText = view.getTitle();
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("in onPageFinished. titleText = %s", titleText));
                mTitleTextView.setText(String.format("Title: %s", titleText));
            }
        });

        final WebSettings browserSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        browserSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/jqmTest.html");
    }
}
```

Here is some sample HTML:

```
<html lang="en" class="ui-mobile">
<head>
    <title>Send a message</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div history="false" data-role="page" data-cache="false" id="signal" data-url="signal" tabindex="0"
     class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 486px;">
    <div data-role="content" class="content ui-content" role="main">
        <h2>Send a message <a href="#help" class="information ui-link" id="signalInfoBox">(help)</a></h2>

        <div class="text">
            <p>We'll send a message to your destination.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divAction" class="response">
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="yes-single">
                <a href="#" id="sendsignal" data-role="button" data-theme="c"
                   class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow">
                    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Send</span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" class="ui-page ui-body-a ui-body-c" id="help" data-url="help" data-external-page="false"
     tabindex="0" style="min-height: 526px;">
    <div data-role="content" class="content ui-content" role="main">
        <h2>More Info</h2>
        <div class="text">
            <p>You can send a message to your selected destination. Just click Send.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="response">
        <div class="buttons">
            <a id="btnCancel" href="#signal"
               class="cancel-button ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-up-undefined"
               style="padding: 10px 0;" data-role="button">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</html>
```

When the user clicks the (help) link to navigate to #help, the help div is displayed and the title retrieved by getTitle() is correct. When the user then clicks the close button, in onPageFinished() the call to view.getTitle()  returns the page URL and not the Html title.

Why does veiw.getTitle() return the page url?

I'm testing this on a Motorola Moto E running Android 4.4.4. The targeted SDK is API 19. This does not appear to occur on Android 4.4.2 or 5.x. Is this a known issue with 4.4.4?

Comment: sir when the page loads for the first time does the getTitle() get it right?

Comment: Yes, the first time the page loads (and displays the id="signal" div) the title is correct. Click the (help) link, and the title is still correct. Then click close, and then title is wrong. Also, it appears that onPageFinished() is called twice for each page load. Is this a side effect of jQueryMobile?

Comment: honestly sir, i can't tell, but from the webview docs it says getTitle is the title of the page until onTitleReceived gets called, so im guess you pull the title once and save somewhere, because its not after that interface is called, honestly these are all guesses,

Comment: I hadn't noticed that comment about "until onReceivedTitle is called". I will do some experiments and let you know. I stopped relying on onReceivedTitle because of https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=481570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the Android Chromium WebView bug (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=481570) I could not use onReceivedTitle() callback in setWebChromeClient() for Android versions 4.4 and later. Instead I created a workaround using the onPageFinished() callback of setWebViewClient(). This however appears to have a bug in Android 4.4.4 where sometimes the page URL is returned when view.getTitle() is called.

In jQueryMobile navigation between DIVs in a page, the call to view.getTitle() in the following sometimes returns the page URL and not the Html title

```
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    String titleText = view.getTitle(); 
  }
```

As a workaround, I put in something like the following:

```
  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url); 

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        String javascript = "(function() { " +
          "var titles = document.getElementsByTagName(\"title\");" +
          "if (titles == null || titles.length != 1) return \"\";" +
          "return titles[0].textContent; " +
          "})();";

        browser.evaluateJavascript(javascript, new ValueCallback<String>() {
           @Override
           public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
             String htmlTitleString = s.replace("\"", "");
             if (htmlTitleString != null && htmlTitleString.length() > 0) {
                title.setText(htmlTitleString);
             }
          }
        });
    } else {
        String titleText = view.getTitle();
        if (titleText != null && titleText.length() > 0) {
           title.setText(titleText);
        }
    }
  }
```

This extracts the HTML title from the WebView DOM in KitKat and later. So far this seems reliable. I find it hard to believe that this was necessary and nobody else has stumbled on these issues. I don't feel like we are doing something out of the ordinary.